# Python - create tree from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I have a problem, I must create a function that create a tree from a dictionary of any numbers of elements.
Example of dictionaries:

```
D1 = {'name': 'musica',
      'children': [
          {'name': 'rock',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'origini', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'rock&roll', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'hard rock', 'children': []}]},
          {'name': 'jazz',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'origini',
                'children': [{'name': '1900',
                              'children': [{'name': 'origini', 'children': []}]}]},
               {'name': 'ragtime', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'swing', 'children': []}]}]}

D2 = {'name': 'html',
      'children': [
          {'name': 'head',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'meta', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'title', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'style', 'children': []}]},
          {'name': 'body',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'h1', 'children': []},
               {'name': 'section',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'p',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'strong', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'b', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'em', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'i', 'children': []}]},
                    {'name': 'p',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'q', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'code', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'kbd', 'children': []}]},
                    {'name': 'p',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'sup', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'sub', 'children': []}]},
                    {'name': 'p',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'span', 'children': []}]}]},
               {'name': 'footer',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'a',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'strong', 'children': []}]},
                    {'name': 'a',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'strong', 'children': []}]}]}]}]}

D3 = {'name': 'Giovanni di Bicci',
      'children': [
          {'name': 'Cosimo il vecchio',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'Piero il gottuso',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'Lorenzo il magnifico',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'Piero II',
                          'children': [
                              {'name': 'Lorenzo II', 'children': []}]},
                         {'name': 'Papa Leone X', 'children': []},
                         {'name': 'Giuliano', 'children': []}]}]},
               {'name': 'Giovanni Carlo', 'children': []}]},
          {'name': 'Lorenzo',
           'children': [
               {'name': 'Pierfrancesco',
                'children': [
                    {'name': 'Lorenzo', 'children': []},
                    {'name': 'Giovanni',
                     'children': [
                         {'name': 'Giovanni dalle Bande Nere',
                          'children': [
                              {'name': 'Lorenzino', 'children': []},
                              {'name': 'Cosimo I',
                               'children': [
                                   {'name': 'Francesco I',
                                    'children': [
                                        {'name': 'Maria', 'children': []}]},
                                   {'name': 'Ferdinando I',
                                    'children': {}}]}]}]}]}]}]}
```

Any solution?

Thanks a lot

## ADDITION

Thank you all for the answers.

Now I write the full exercise so you can better understand and answer me: Actually I have implemented a class TNode made in these methods:

```
class TNode(object):

def __init__(self, name, Sinistra= None, Destra= None):
    self._name = name
    self.Destra = Destra
    self.Sinistra = Sinistra
    self._children = []
    self._copy = []
    self.c = c
    
def add(self, c): 
    self._children.append(c)
 

def children(self):
    self._copy = self._children
    return self._copy
    
def height(self):
    h = 1
    for node in self._children:
        h = max(h, node.height() + 1)
    return h
    
def count(self):
    c = 1
    for node in self._children:
        c += node.count()
    return c

 def count_by_name(self, name):
    lst = []
    if self._name == name: 
        lst += [self]
    for node in self._children:
        lst += node.count_by_name(name)
    return lst
    
def leaves(self):
    leaves_s = []
    if not self._children:
        leaves_s.append(self.c)
    for node in self._children:
        leaves_s.update(node.leaves())
    return len(leaves_s)
    
def paths(self, name):
    paths_s = set()
    if self._name == name:
        paths_s.add((name,))
    for node in self._children:
        for j in node.paths(name):
            paths_s.add((self._name,)+j)
    return paths_s
```

I also need to create a function create_tree(d) that, taken a Dictionary "d" that represents a tree, creates the corresponding tree with nodes of type TNode and returns the root. The function must add the children in the same order as they are listed in the lists of the keys 'children'.

Sorry if initially I did not write all that.

I fail to create the function, referred to the class, that create a tree from a dictionary.

I use Python 2.7

Thanks.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Please, try to format your code a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post by adding the class which should I tell the function create_tree(d).

Answer (score 5):

You can create a tree with [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def Tree():
    return defaultdict(Tree)
```

Then using it:

```
>>> tree = Tree()
>>> tree['house']['car']['red']['hubcap'] = 1950
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. I edited the post by adding the class which should I tell the function create_tree(d). How should be changed your solution to work with the class Tode ()?

Comment: Sorry Peter I don't understand because at the end of my message it appears " edited 38 mins ago Peter Wood 8.934 "... And if I click in, it appears: "Made dictionary fit on screen"...What does it means? Sorry I'm new to the forum. Thanks

Comment: I edited your question because the example data wouldn't fit across the screen and was difficult to read. The structure wasn't apparent. Hopefully it's clearer now. I think you probably posted too much data. A little would have been enough to get the idea. When asking questions it's best not to just dump everything. Be as specific as possible about your problem, the thing you don't understand, strip everything else away. If a line of code doesn't make your example clearer, get rid of it. But make sure the example works to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks a lot for the suggestions.  I hope I have explained in a comprehensible way my problem: to create a function create_tree(d) that, taken a Dictionary "d" that represents a tree, creates the corresponding tree with nodes of type TNode and returns the root. The function must add the children in the same order as they are listed in the lists of the keys 'children'. Woud you know how I can implement it? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the amazing thing about Stack Overflow is that you are on view to the whole world. Once you start asking an individual (me) to troubleshoot your problems you've lost the value of SO. I don't have the time to answer further. Of course I know how to implement it, but I'm not a tutor, and that's not what SO is about. Try to take the next step yourself, and if you don't know, ask a very specific question, not of me but of SO. I'm part of SO, so maybe I'll see it and answer.

Comment: Sure, i understand. I try to implement it and then I will ask to SO help by specific question. Sorry, thank you.